# How to use switch/case (simple pattern matching) in Scala?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, switch-statement

I've found myself stuck on a very trivial thing :-]

I've got an enum:

```
 object Eny extends Enumeration {
      type Eny = Value
      val FOO, BAR, WOOZLE, DOOZLE = Value
    }
```

In a code I have to convert it conditionally to a number (varianr-number correspondence differs on context). I write:

```
val en = BAR
val num = en match {
  case FOO => 4
  case BAR => 5
  case WOOZLE => 6
  case DOOZLE => 7
}
```

And this gives me an "unreachable code" compiler error for every branch but whatever is the first ("case FOO => 4" in this case). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that "en" is "val" and assigned to "BAR". It can not be reassigned later so it's equals to BAR anywhere after such declaration.

Comment: It's a simplified example, in real program "en" is a function's input argument. It indeed can't be reassigned inside, but can differ from call to call.

Comment: In that case, perhaps you can give a less simplified example? As it stands, the answer is that it gives "unreachable code" error because there is unreachable code.

Comment: I cannot replicate the error you report. I took your code, unchanged, put it inside an object and compiled it. Did you submit it to the REPL?

Comment: Fascinating. After I've isolated the sample in a separate simple .scala file, compiled and ran it - it works as expected. But inside my program it does not. Seems I'll need my tambourine...

Comment: I've replaced match-case with if-else-if. Does not look pretty but works at least.

Comment: @Ivan - post your *actual* code! You'll get your solution pretty quickly, I suspect!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I suspect the code you are actually using is not `FOO`, but `foo`, lowercase, which will cause Scala to just assign the value to `foo`, instead of comparing the value to it.

In other words:

```
x match {
  case A => // compare x to A, because of the uppercase
  case b => // assign x to b
  case `b` => // compare x to b, because of the backtick
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And what can I do to use lowercase enum values?

Comment: @Ivan: Put them inside backticks as shown in his third example.

Answer (score 7):

The following code works fine for me: it produces 6

```
object Eny extends Enumeration {
  type Eny = Value
  val FOO, BAR, WOOZLE, DOOZLE = Value
}

import Eny._

class EnumTest {
    def doit(en: Eny) = {
        val num = en match {
          case FOO => 4
          case BAR => 5
          case WOOZLE => 6
          case DOOZLE => 7
        }       

        num
    }
}

object EnumTest {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {
        println("" + new EnumTest().doit(WOOZLE))
    }
}
```

Could you say how this differs from your problem please?

Comment: In my real code I have to use lowercases. Daniel says this is the problem. I could never suppose this can matter.

Comment: @pagoda_5b 2ns link is dead. Did someone salvaged it somewhere ?

Comment: @Arioch'The I'm sorry for the missing link. I suppose the topic was considered too generic for the SO format. I have no substitute at the moment.