# Evaluate expression according to the first true condition

Tags: javascript, scala, pattern-matching, switch-statement

In javascript we can do things like this:

```
 switch (true) {
            case a > b:
                expression;
                break;
            case a < b:
                expression;
                break;
            case a == b:
                expression;
                break;
        }
```

Can we achieve something like this in Scala? `If` expression is not the case.

Maximum that I could figure out is:

```
val a = foo < elem
val b = foo > elem
val c = foo == elem
true match {
  case `a` =>
  case `b` =>
  case `c` =>
}
```

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639150/how-to-use-switch-case-simple-pattern-matching-in-scala

Comment: Please read carefully it's not duplicate.

Comment: Would `if/else if/else` work for you?

Comment: Don't fight the language. Just use if, else if, else, end if.

Comment: To fight language is best way to learn it, I think)

Comment: The case must be a value (in scala pattern matching) it cannot be an expression. You can use constants or constructors for cases.

Comment: You could do exactly that with pattern matching, but that would be stretching it. *I think* it would be better to revise the underlying problem to find the solution which would go with the language, not against it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest that I can think of:

```
() match {
  case _ if foo < elem => expression1
  case _ if foo > elem => expression2
  case _ => expression3
}
```

But that's clearly not as natural as if/else if/else. Pattern matching is great but there are definitely cases where you're better off using a good ol' if/else block.

Comment: Cool, I definitely wouldn't use it in production code, but it reminded me about some features I could use in pattern matching thanks)

Answer (score 1):

If you really like scala and like to redefine the language, you can redefine <, > and == as objects with an unapply method. Then you can consider a < b as an extraction:

```
trait Comparator {
    def unapply(t: (Int, Int)): Option[(Int, Int)] = if(compare(t._1, t._2)) Some(t) else None
    val compare: (Int, Int) => Boolean
}
object < extends Comparator {
  val compare = (i: Int, j: Int) => i < j
}
object > extends Comparator {
  val compare = (i: Int, j: Int) => i > j
}
object == extends Comparator {
  val compare = (i: Int, j: Int) => i == j
}

val a = 1
val b = 2
(a, b) match {
  case a < b =>  println(s"$a is less than $b")
  case a > b =>  println(s"$a is greater than $b")
  case a == b => println(s"$a is equal to $b")
}
```

results in:

```
"1 is less than 2"
```

In this case, the a and b inside the pattern matching are extracted variables from (a, b) and the computation is done during the extraction.

Comment: Another great idea, how could I forget about unapply?) +1

Answer (score 0):

would `(a compare b) match { case _ > 0: / case _ < 0 / case _ == 0 }` work? this should work for anything that can be implicitly cast to a Ordered, and would not require capturing outside variables.